# |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field

Tags: python, django

i've a error in my view django (|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field), becose tell me the error here. i don't understand. The template works for me correctly but when saving data it doesn't work for me. This is my code:

**views.py**

````
    my_form  = AlumnoForm()
    my_form2 = ApoderadoForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_form = AlumnoForm(request.POST) and ApoderadoForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid() and my_form2.is_valid():
            print(my_form.cleaned_data)
            print(my_form2.cleaned_data)
            Alumno.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)
            Apoderado.objects.create(**my_form2.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('list_student')
        else:
            print(my_form.errors)
            print(my_form2.errors)

    extra_context = {
        'form' : my_form,
        'form2': my_form2
    }
    return render(request, "create_student.html", extra_context) ```
````

Comment: can you show us the full error

Comment: @Joseph Rajchwald the error in my template tells me `CrispyError at / create_student /
| as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field` `Error during template rendering`. Just This

Comment: @JosephRajchwald That's why I think it's in the last line of views.py